# Deploying existing Nodejs module to WebAssembly

Tags: node.js, node-modules, webassembly

I have written a code in nodejs in which I am able to get block details on localhost using web3. Now I am trying to deploy the same nodejs module to Web assembly.

So, how can I deploy the same using WebAssembly.
You can have a look at my current nodejs code here : [Github Link to chainLinker](https://github.com/Ajitchy/ChainLinker/tree/main)

Currently, I am getting output like shown below. I am just showing the blocknumber and price in console and also on localhost.

```
PS C:\Users\msi\Downloads\UniswapPriceMonitor-main> node index.js
BlockNumber: 15064092 Price ETH/DAI : 1050.63548627748881905413
Chain Connect listening on port 3000!
```

Comment: Take a look at [Node.js with WebAssembly
 Docs](https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-with-webassembly)